# Хороша/правильна структура відповіді?

Tags: discussion, quality-content

Виникло питання щодо структури відповіді. На разі, можна зустріти різні варіанти написання відповідей:

- дослідження, потім відповідь;
- відповідь в середині тексту;
- відповідь в самому кінці;
- нехає чіткої відповіді, запропоновано декілька варіантів + обгрунтування.

На мій погляд, всі ці структури не є зручними для користувачів, оскільки їм потрібно читати весь обсяг відповіді, а часто потрібна лише правильна відповідь.

Чи є якість усталені формати відповідей для лінгвістичних сайтів? Чи є сенс давати декілька відповідей від однієї людини, якщо немає єдиного прийнятного  варіанту відповіді (зокрема, при обговоренні перекладу термінів, що не мають усталеного варіанту)?

Зі своєї сторони практикую такий підхід відповіді:

> **Спочатку вказуємо правильну відповідь і відділяємо її - або рискою або жирним шрифтом.**
>
> ---
>
> Потім безпосередньо пишемо текст відповіді з цитатами, коментарями та дослідженнями.

Answer (score 2):

По-моєму, Ви намагаєтеся формалізувати те, що не можна формалізувати. Для різних відповідей найкращим може бути різний формат. [Тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/252301) і [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) про формат навіть натяків нема.

Типу, на колір і смак товариш не всяк. Хоча, звісно, не буде нічого страшного, якщо Ви використовуватимете для себе весь час один і той самий формат. Чи навіть запропонуєте його іншим. Але щось мені не віриться в підведення якогось фундаменту під це. Мені здається, формат в першу чергу задається змістом відповіді, настроєм відповіді та характером/звичками її автора.

Щодо двох відповідей від однієї людини — так роблять рідко, але це не забороняється. Я б робив так в тому і лише в тому випадку, коли хочу представити іншу відповідь з абсолютно нової перспективи (наче від іншої людини). В інших випадках намагався би об'єднувати. Але це, знов таки, чисто особистий погляд, який може значно відрізнятися від погляду іншої людини.

Answer (score 2):

Як правильно зазначає @Sasha, формальної відповіді нема. Але натомість є загальні рекомендації StackExchange, із яких, у свою чергу, кожен може (дещо по-своєму) вивести прийнятні правила для себе.

Наприклад:

- Ваша відповідь має **відповідати на конкретне запитання**, тобто, влаштовувати топік-стартера. Значить, воно має містити дослідження, обґрунтування тощо;
- Але **ми тут задля того, щоб вчитися**, а значить, відповідь також має вчити тих користувачів, хто прийдуть пізніше.
  Тим користувачам, можливо, не потрібне детальне пояснення. Вони хочуть *швидко* зрозуміти запитання і коротку відповідь. І *не читати* відповідь цілком, щоб знайти оту одну ключову фразу. А значить, що «коротка відповідь» має бути помітною;
- Якщо відповідь не має, власне, відповіді, але ви маєте серйозну упевненість, що відповідь **дає напрямок** до подальших досліджень — така відповідь має право на існування, але варто одразу прямо написати, що відповідь не є остаточною;

А стиль і оформлення — це, дійсно, на авторський розсуд.